Read ConfigurationManager.AppSettings for LinqPad 8
I have a problem with the read of configurationmanager.appsettings, I want to debug with LINQPad 8 a program with a DLL library that I create.
The problem is that the DLL library take a URL of a webserver from the config file (app.config if is a desktop software or web.config if it's a web app) but I don't know how to do this in linqpad 8.
In my DLL I use this instruction to take the URL of webserver (after I call the API from this URL):
string url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Url"];

How can I fix it?
Thanks.
The code for LINQPad 8 or the code of LINQPad.config/appsettings.json takes that variable from ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.

The instructions may differ with Linqpad version 5 and lower, but this works for me with versions 6, 7 and 8.
Copy your app.config and save it with the correct name which depends on your version of LinqPad.

For LinqPad 6 this should be LINQPad6.Query.dll.config
For LinqPad 7 this should be LINQPad7.Query.dll.config
For LinqPad 8 this should be LINQPad.Query.dll.config

In your query, add this file to your references (i.e. F4, Additional References/ Browse)
Your query should now work.
If you don't have an existing app.config, you can just create one like below
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Url" value="https://www.google.com" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>

